# How to read POST data with multiple bracets?

Tags: php

I have a form, which gets submitted in this form (according to chrome):

```
form[1][value][0][translation]:myValue
```

But i dont know how to access this in php.

This is what i tried so far:

```
$myVariable = $_POST["form"]["1"]["value"]["0"]["translation"];
```

This unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Could you use `print_r($_POST)` and tell us what is the output?

Comment: Please add to your question the output from `print_r($_POST)` it is not easy to help with this question without knowing exactly what `$_POST` looks like

Comment: What is your form code?

Comment: I would guess at `$_POST["value"][0]["translation"];` as only the contents of which ever form you are submitting are sent to PHP so `['form1']` bit is irrelevant is PHP